# iOS PayPal MPL, how to refund payment?

Tags: ios, paypal

Any help would be awesome. I'm using PayPal MPL to take payment from customer in iOS, but in certain scenario something goes wrong with the transaction and I need to issue a refund to the customer. I should have the Payment ID from the transaction. Is it possible to make a call using PayPal MPL to initiate the refund? Thanks in advance!

I see sample of this being achieved from a server-side, but wanting to see if this is possible doing it from the app instead.